# AWS S3 only allow Cloudfront access

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

So in order to make it so that S3 objects must be accessed through Cloudfront, the instructions are to go into your Cloudfront distribution settings, then Origins, then set Yes to `Restrict Bucket Access`. I also select `Yes, Update Bucket Policy`.

I then go into my S3 bucket and see that the Cloudfront access policy is in place, and that the only permissions present on the bucket is access for my user account.

However, I can still access S3 bucket objects with their respective S3 urls.

The catch is that the objects are created with read permissions for everyone, but shouldn't bucket policy, and even the Cloudfront policy, trump independent object policy?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend taking a look at [Using ACLs and Bucket Policies Together](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingACLsandBucketPoliciesTogether.html) S3 documentation.

> With existing Amazon S3 ACLs, a grant always provides access to a
>   bucket or object. When using policies, a deny always overrides a
>   grant.

Comment: Broken link. See http://web.archive.org/web/20140326034054/http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingACLsandBucketPoliciesTogether.html